# Sending file from Php to web service

Tags: php, web-services, file

I have a web-service that accepts file as a Post request and upload it on the server and returns the file path.

The service is working properly though Ajax request. But now i want to make a request from Php to the web service and its giving me error that "Undefined index: imageFile"

The code i am trying to use is below

```
$filename = 'e:/e.jpg';

$fields = array('imageFile'=>$filename);

$fieldsQueryString = http_build_query($fields);

// you should have curl library install here 
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/uploadapi/index.php/api/example/imageupload"); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsQueryString);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add @ (eta) sign before file path to upload it.

For more, read at PHP manual for [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS setting.

```
<?php
$filename = '@e:/e.jpg';
$fields = array('imageFile'=>$filename); 
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1/uploadapi/index.php/api/example/imageupload");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsQueryString);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to use

curl_file_create()

object to create the file and send it to the web service. Just did it and its working like a charm

Thanks